# my group_by and mutate functions are not properly working

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I want to use the max function for each Item in my dataframe, but when I use group_by, it outputs the Items for each Area. I should just have a distinct set of Items though-not duplicate Items. When I replace mutate with summarize, the output is correct; however, I need the Area along with Item and max.

```
food <- read_csv("data/FAO.csv") %>%
  filter(Element == "Food") %>%
  select(Area, Item, Y2010) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(max = max(Y2010))
```

Comment: Please provide some data along with the code, with the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can select which value of `Area` you want from each `Item`.

For example, to select first item you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

food <- read_csv("data/FAO.csv") %>%
  filter(Element == "Food") %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  summarise(max = max(Y2010), 
            Area = first(Area))
```

Or use `Area` in `group_by` :

```
library(dplyr)

food <- read_csv("data/FAO.csv") %>%
  filter(Element == "Food") %>%
  group_by(Item, Area) %>%
  summarise(max = max(Y2010))
```